# Не работает метод onBackPressed Android

Tags: java, android

Есть проект "написанный" в Buildbox и импортированный в Android Studio. В самой студии была создана Activity с кнопкой, при нажатии на которую открывается другая Activity где подгружаются ресурсы игры и открывается меню. При вызове метода onBackPressed приложение просто закрывается вместо того чтобы вернуться на предыдущую Activity, логи пустые, все без ошибок, но метод не срабатывает.

код первой Activity:

```
package com.companyname.gamename;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m);
    }

    public void btnStart (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MActivity.this, PTPlayer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

код второй Activty:

```
package com.companyname.gamename;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.secrethq.store.PTStoreBridge;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;

import com.secrethq.ads.*;
import com.secrethq.utils.*;

public class PTPlayer extends Cocos2dxActivity {

    private static native void loadModelController();

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            Log.v("----------","onActivityResult: request: " + requestCode + " result: "+ resultCode);
            if(PTStoreBridge.iabHelper().handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)){
                Log.v("-----------", "handled by IABHelper");
            }
            else if(requestCode == PTServicesBridge.RC_SIGN_IN){
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    PTServicesBridge.instance().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
                else if(resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_SIGN_IN_FAILED){
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services: Sign in error", duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else if(resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_APP_MISCONFIGURED){
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services: App misconfigured", duration);
                    toast.show();               
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("-----------", "onActivityResult FAIL on iabHelper : " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PTServicesBridge.initBridge(this, getString( R.string.app_id ));
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNativeInit(){
            initBridges();              
    }

    private void initBridges(){
        PTStoreBridge.initBridge( this );


        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
            PTAdChartboostBridge.initBridge(this);
        }

        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kRevMob")) {
            PTAdRevMobBridge.initBridge(this);
        }

        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kAdMob") || PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kFacebook")) {
            PTAdAdMobBridge.initBridge(this);
        }

        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kAppLovin")) {
            PTAdAppLovinBridge.initBridge(this);
        }

        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kLeadBolt")) {
            PTAdLeadBoltBridge.initBridge(this);
        }

        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kFacebook")) {
            PTAdFacebookBridge.initBridge(this);
        }

        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kHeyzap")) {
            PTAdHeyzapBridge.initBridge(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView onCreateView() {
        Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = new Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView(this);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0);

        return glSurfaceView;
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("player");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //MemoryManager.onBackPressed();
        //exitConfirmation(this);
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, MActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
            PTAdChartboostBridge.onResume( this );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
            PTAdChartboostBridge.onStart( this );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (PTJniHelper.isAdNetworkActive("kChartboost")) {
            PTAdChartboostBridge.onStop( this );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

логи:

```
2019-06-09 00:43:53.872 11254-11254/? I/zygote: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-06-09 00:43:53.971 11254-11262/? E/zygote: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
2019-06-09 00:43:53.972 11254-11262/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
2019-06-09 00:43:54.111 11254-11254/? I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2019-06-09 00:43:54.111 11254-11254/? I/MultiDex: Installing application
2019-06-09 00:43:54.111 11254-11254/? I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2019-06-09 00:43:54.130 11254-11254/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
2019-06-09 00:43:54.324 11254-11299/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-06-09 00:43:54.380 11254-11299/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : d916c72, I7663a5f222
    Build Date                       : 10/04/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.22.00.01_06_07
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2019-06-09 00:43:54.387 11254-11299/? I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
2019-06-09 00:43:54.392 11254-11299/? I/com.companyname.gamename: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-06-09 00:43:54.393 11254-11299/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-06-09 00:43:54.393 11254-11299/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-06-09 00:43:58.923 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename D/JniHelper: JniHelper::setJavaVM(0xef719140), pthread_self() = -216894300
2019-06-09 00:43:58.981 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename D/Cocos2dxActivity: model=Redmi 4 Prime
2019-06-09 00:43:58.982 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename D/Cocos2dxActivity: product=markw
2019-06-09 00:43:58.982 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename D/Cocos2dxActivity: isEmulator=false
2019-06-09 00:43:59.017 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename W/SoundPool: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
2019-06-09 00:43:59.017 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename W/SoundPool: See the documentation of SoundPool() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
2019-06-09 00:43:59.018 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename V/PTServicesBridge: PTServicesBridge  -- INIT
2019-06-09 00:43:59.021 11254-11254/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPSettingsController] - loadInventoryMap
2019-06-09 00:43:59.083 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] -- Cleaning
2019-06-09 00:43:59.095 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelGeneralSettings.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.098 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelFont.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.099 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelScreen.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.101 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectLabel.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.141 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelScreen.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.141 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPAppDelegate] game loading: start
2019-06-09 00:43:59.264 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPAppDelegate] device orientation: 1
2019-06-09 00:43:59.264 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPAppDelegate] screen adjustment: 0
2019-06-09 00:43:59.268 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPSettingsController] - loadInventoryMap
2019-06-09 00:43:59.270 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck: Running on a non-TV Device
2019-06-09 00:43:59.290 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: scale X: 1.690141 Y: 1.690141
2019-06-09 00:43:59.291 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPAppDelegate] loading time: 0.025731
2019-06-09 00:43:59.291 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] -- Cleaning
2019-06-09 00:43:59.296 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPScreenStart] banner: kNoAds interstitial: kNoAds
2019-06-09 00:43:59.431 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelGeneralSettings.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.528 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectEventObserver.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.577 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButtonFacebook.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.611 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectImage.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.694 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetUnit.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.829 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentCharacterGameplaySettings.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.898 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButtonControl.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:43:59.949 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetParticles.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.032 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentWakeup.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.098 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelAnimation.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.130 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentDeletionThreshold.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.183 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButtonSoundControl.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.232 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetLight.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.283 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectBackground.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.315 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelFont.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.366 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelAtlas.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.415 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelSpriteContainer.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.464 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelScreenScene.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.515 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelLevelSection.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.549 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelScreen.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.582 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelLinker.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.631 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelSprite.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.731 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelAssetCharacter.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.766 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTNodeScene.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.799 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTNodeUI.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.849 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButton.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.881 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTNodeUIStart.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.914 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelAssetObstacle.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.947 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentHealth.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:00.982 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelAssetPowerup.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.031 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetCharacter.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.082 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectLabel.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.148 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetLogic.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.179 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetParticlesEmitter.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.298 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetPowerup.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.349 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(0) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetScreenJump.0.attributes.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.398 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelGeneralSettings.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.480 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectEventObserver.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.530 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButtonFacebook.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.563 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectImage.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.596 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetUnit.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.629 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentCharacterGameplaySettings.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.698 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButtonControl.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.748 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetParticles.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.832 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentWakeup.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.898 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelAnimation.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.932 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentDeletionThreshold.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:01.981 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButtonSoundControl.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.032 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetLight.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.082 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectBackground.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.115 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelFont.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.165 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelAtlas.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.215 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelSpriteContainer.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.265 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelScreenScene.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.315 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelLevelSection.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.347 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelScreen.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.380 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelLinker.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.431 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelSprite.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.532 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelAssetCharacter.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.565 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTNodeScene.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.598 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTNodeUI.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.649 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectButton.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.683 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTNodeUIStart.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.716 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelAssetObstacle.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.749 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelComponentHealth.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.782 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelAssetPowerup.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.831 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetCharacter.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.881 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectLabel.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.915 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetLogic.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:02.948 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetParticlesEmitter.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:03.031 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetPowerup.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:03.081 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTModelController] load data(1) for class from file: data/PTModelObjectAssetScreenJump.0.connections.xml
2019-06-09 00:44:03.117 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: End loading XML
2019-06-09 00:44:03.117 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPSettingsController] - loadInventoryMap
2019-06-09 00:44:03.117 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPSettingsController] - load
2019-06-09 00:44:03.149 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: invenotory count: 0
2019-06-09 00:44:03.150 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: characters count: 1
2019-06-09 00:44:03.150 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: load character: PTP_Character_0 = 0:1
2019-06-09 00:44:03.153 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPSettingsController] - load complete
2019-06-09 00:44:03.153 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: Init Android JNI Bridges
2019-06-09 00:44:03.169 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename E/PTServicesBridge: PTServicesBridge  -- loadingDidComplete
2019-06-09 00:44:03.169 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename V/PTServicesBridge: PTServicesBridge  -- Login Game Services 
2019-06-09 00:44:03.169 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTAdController] init Ad Networks
2019-06-09 00:44:03.169 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: Platform: Google Play
2019-06-09 00:44:03.170 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: Start Atlas loading
2019-06-09 00:44:03.170 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: loading atlas
2019-06-09 00:44:03.170 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: data/atlases/atlas_ID107.plist
2019-06-09 00:44:03.406 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: loading atlas
2019-06-09 00:44:03.407 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: data/atlases/atlas_ID2330.plist
2019-06-09 00:44:03.544 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: loading screens
2019-06-09 00:44:03.546 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck: Running on a non-TV Device
2019-06-09 00:44:03.548 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPScreenMainMenuUI] banner: kNoAds interstitial: kNoAds
2019-06-09 00:44:07.870 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPInputController] key Down clicked
2019-06-09 00:44:07.870 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename V/PTPLAYER: KEY DOWN4
2019-06-09 00:44:07.903 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPInputController] key UP clicked
2019-06-09 00:44:07.903 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: key Back CLCIKED
2019-06-09 00:44:07.903 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPScreenUi] keyBackClicked
2019-06-09 00:44:07.903 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPSettingsController] - save
2019-06-09 00:44:07.935 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename D/PTPlayer: [PTPSettingsController] - save complete
2019-06-09 00:44:07.936 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename V/PTPLAYER: KEY UP4
2019-06-09 00:44:07.939 11254-11320/com.companyname.gamename I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11254 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому вдруг понадобится, нужно убрать `finish()` из метода `btnStart` первой `Activity`, иначе в стеке ничего не остаётся.

Это:

```
public void btnStart (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MActivity.this, PTPlayer.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Исправить так:

```
public void btnStart (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MActivity.this, PTPlayer.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```